# How to make background apps/ automatic apps use only wifi for data?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data

Ok so i have very little data, 100mb. And i want to use it when i need it. Like for maps etc.

But some apps keep downloading stuff such as new articles and all data gets eaten quickly without me using it. I'm about uninstall every app that does this if i don't find a solution.

This is what i want.

for auto/background apps Use internett only through wifi.
and if i use internet first use wifi if available and then go to mobile data.

im glad there're no overhead charges, data just becomes unavailable after limit.

Answer (score 0):

/system/bin/iptables (usually built in) is the tool, but I prefer a graphical frontend for it such as AFWall+ which is available from the Play store or F-Droid.
If you are going to be using TOR then OrWall should also work, but I haven't tried it.

These tools show one app per row & columns for the interfaces you wish to allow them to use & you just tick the boxes.

Comment: what.. im lost.. should i download afwall?

Comment: yes, and use it to set up which apps get full access & which are restricted

Answer (score 0):

Use **Background Data Restriction** (settings>data usage>menu>[check] Background Restriction) while using data from SIM.

While using WiFi Disable it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a setting for that, at least in CyanogenMod: [image: settings app] [image: menu option]

Comment: consider the remote chance that he's not using the same rom. Probably he's not using any rom at all

Comment: I think that this option is available on all ROMs, even stock ones.

Comment: i flashed my android phone to use remix mod or something. It's awesome. It has option to set data limits, However, despite me setting limit to 80mb it still surpassed 100mb somehow. So this is why i want to completely disable auto use of data over mobile network.

Comment: There is an option for that! Check the overflow menu for such setting!

Comment: i dont have overflow menu...also this is all in russian i think, so i dont have much clue beside that diagram with line it. That looked similar to mine. except is in dark theme.

Comment: The highlighted option is "restrict background data", is there an option like that?